# Spray and akka-http throughput decreased significantly on response length change

Tags: performance, scala, jvm, spray, akka-http

I benchmark spray and akka-http to be aware of possible throughput I can get. Tested application is simple. It returns static output on static GET path. But in case of both frameworks I get throughput decreased from ~64000 to ~22000 rps when static response length is increased from 7 to ~2040 characters.

Does anybody else experienced such behavior? How can the situation be improved?

Tested code can be found here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/olga-gorun/825e823027aadb2962b3b7229e4d5d48)

It is inspired by test described in [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/XB7H2n2r-9A/NwTZuTOYAgAJ).

Used versions:

ubuntu 14.04, scala 2.11.8, oracle jdk 1.8

akka-http: 2.4.11

spray: 1.3.1 with akka 2.3.6

[Tests results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yuFD7WDOzhWB5_Ob7XgAfFAdWt48SrthbvZSZ45GE-k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You are returning 300 times as much data but get only a slowdown of factor 3. That still sounds good. So, you went from pushing 7*64000 = 448000 B/s to 2040*22000 = 44880000 B/s which is still quite an increase overall.

Comment: Well, wrk shows increase from ~9MB/s to ~11MB/s. But I don't see from AWS CloudWatch something similar to network saturation. I don't think network is my bottleneck. I also don't see CPU or memory saturation: CPU usage is decreased from 80% to 60%. Memory is increased from 0.5GB to 1.5GB (with 14GB free in the system). CPU interrupts are not increased significantly. So why spray/ akka-http should be able to process significantly less requests?

Comment: @jrudolph, sorry. I repeated my tests and saw a mistake. Throughput in MB/s is increased from ~9MB/s to ~70MB/s. I added also variant with scalatra to the benchmark set (code is added to the same gist) and saw similar throughput with long output. It looks like network bandwidth limitation. On the other hand iperf from with client to server with default parameters gives me ~88MB/s. How can I better check this hypothesis? Test results can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yuFD7WDOzhWB5_Ob7XgAfFAdWt48SrthbvZSZ45GE-k/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to be network issue.
@jrudolph thank you for emphasizing network throughput.